# How to get multiple values from Arduino "almost" real-time in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, arduino, serial-communication

So I have this C# application which gets values via serial communication from Arduino. I color some circles depending on values of some pins (digital pins). When I run the application I have a little delay, like almost a second which I think is too much. I change the baud rate from 9600 to 112500 (still the same thing). In C# application the "reads" are made by calling some functions in a timer. I changed the timer interval from 100 milliseconds to 20 and still the same delay. What to do ? Also the application is running a little slow, for example if I hover the cursor above minimize button, the button doesn't highlight instantly.

Comment: I'd like to see some code, but I think that the reason for this behavior can be that you wrote a sort of reading thread which never pauses, so the CPU usage is always at 100% even if not necessary.

Comment: I hope isn't too much code...    https://www.dropbox.com/s/igk4l3gkp5mjmga/Desktop.rar

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem (or at least one of the problems).

In your tick event you wrote

private void

```
tempreader_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    red_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 32));
    red_light2 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 33));

    yellow_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 34));
    yellow_light2 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 35));

    green_light1 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 36));
    green_light2 = Convert.ToInt32(comport.message(4, 8, 37));

    [other actions]
```

Your `comport.message` is

```
public string message(byte paramone, byte paramtwo, byte paramthree)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
        buffer[0] = Convert.ToByte(paramone);
        buffer[1] = Convert.ToByte(paramtwo);
        buffer[2] = Convert.ToByte(paramthree);
        currentPort.Open();
        currentPort.Write(buffer, 0, 3);
        int intReturnASCII = 0;
        char charReturnValue = (Char)intReturnASCII;
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        int count = currentPort.BytesToRead;
        string returnMessage = "";
        while (count > 0)
        {
            intReturnASCII = currentPort.ReadByte();
            returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII);
            count--;
        }
        currentPort.Close();
        return returnMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error";
    }

}
```

Which contains `Thread.Sleep(200)`. So it does not matter how fast you call the tick, the main thread will be stuck in that function for at least 1.2 seconds.

You have to reduce this or, if you can't, use something like a `backgroundworker` to do the job and update the GUI in its `runcompleted` event.

Comment: Then there's the utter insanity of all those `Convert` methods, half of which are doing *absolutely nothing at all*.